# On Meta, [scraping] is just a copycat tag

Tags: discussion, retag-request, meta

On Meta Stack Overflow, [scraping](/questions/tagged/scraping) and [copycat-sites](/questions/tagged/copycat-sites) serve the same purpose.

[scraping](/questions/tagged/scraping) has fewer questions, and an irrelevant tag wiki:

> The process of extracting information from the HTML source code of
>   live websites. Typically used by third-party applications to interact
>   with a website that doesn't expose an API. Web scraping (web
>   harvesting or web data extraction) is a computer software technique of
>   extracting information from websites. Usually, such software programs
>   simulate human exploration of the World Wide Web by either
>   implementing low-level Hypertext Transfer Protocol (HTTP), or
>   embedding a fully-fledged web browser, such as Internet Explorer or
>   Mozilla Firefox.
>
> Web scraping is closely related to web indexing, which indexes
>   information on the web using a bot or web crawler and is a universal
>   technique adopted by most search engines. In contrast, web scraping
>   focuses more on the transformation of unstructured data on the web,
>   typically in HTML format, into structured data that can be stored and
>   analyzed in a central local database or spreadsheet. Web scraping is
>   also related to web automation, which simulates human browsing using
>   computer software. Uses of web scraping include online price
>   comparison, contact scraping, weather data monitoring, website change
>   detection, research, web mashup and web data integration.
>
> Copied from: https://stackoverflow.com/tags/web-scraping/info

Can we get rid of "scraping" on Meta?

Comment: Sure you want to get rid of the tag instead of having a tag-synonym? Because the latter would be my inclination for this one.

Comment: @deduplicator a synonym would be fine.